# Html.ActionLink does not render correct link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have created an MVC web application.

I have a problem with `@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")`.

I was expecting the link would take me to localhost:5123/Home/Contact.

Unfortunately it takes me to localhost:5123/?action=Contact&controller=Home

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

It looks like all my `Html.ActionLink` are not working correctly.

Comment: Please post your RouteConfig and where your view resides within the project structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Home")
```

### Update

I presume you want this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, null)
```

Source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Why shouldn't the [`ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070(v=vs.118).aspx) override work?

Comment: I guess his routing. But as he got different result that why I gave those both above

Answer (score 0):

If your view chtml file (which you try to add the link) is not in the Home folder then you need to specify which controller you try to direct.

In best practise try add action link on following way.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link name","Your Action Name",
  "Your Controller Name",
  new {Route paramters},
  new {html attributes})
```

Comment: Hi Guys just a humble request if you mark minus can you please add a comment so then i can learn something and correct my self. Thank you very much